# How to align label in image view?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uilabel

I have a scrollview (IBOutlet); in that scrollview I have added an imageview. I am trying to add a label in the image according to its size. I mean, there are 9 options to put a label in an image: for instance TR (Top Right corner), TC (Top center), C(Center)... Suppose my image is smaller than the iPhone's resolution, say 300x160. Now, I am loading labels in the image view but it's not working properly, the alignment of the label is not correct.
Here is my align button code:

```
-(IBAction)btn_AlignPressed:(UIButton*)sender{
    lbl.tag = sender.tag;
    [imgView addSubview:lbl];
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    } else if(sender.tag == 2) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(160-(imgView.frame.size.width/2), 0, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    } else if(sender.tag == 3) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(320-imgView.frame.size.width, 0, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    } else if(sender.tag == 4) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 210-(imgView.frame.size.height/2), imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    } else if(sender.tag == 5) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(160-(imgView.frame.size.width/2), 210-(imgView.frame.size.height/2), imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    } else if(sender.tag == 6) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(320-imgView.frame.size.width, 210-(imgView.frame.size.height/2), imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    } else if(sender.tag == 7) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 420-imgView.frame.size.height, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    } else if(sender.tag == 8) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(160-(imgView.frame.size.width/2), 420-imgView.frame.size.height, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    } else if(sender.tag == 9) {
        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(320-imgView.frame.size.width, 420-imgView.frame.size.height, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only setting x and y values, you will also have to work on the width and height of your label.